# jQuery CSS set scale of child element without altering translation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I prevent `.css("-webkit-transform", ...` from removing an already existing translation of an element?

HTML & CSS:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child" style="-webkit-transform:translate(10px,60px) scale(0.6);"></div>
    <div class="child" style="-webkit-transform:translate(80px,12px) scale(0.4);"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".parent").children(".child").css("-webkit-transform", "scale(0.9)");
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qET8N/)

Answer (score 1):

Simply concatenate the values:

```
$(".parent").children(".child").css("-webkit-transform", function(i, value) {
    return value + " scale(0.9)";
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/qET8N/1/

Comment: How can I prevent the scale from being added up each time the `Scale` button is clicked? I'd like all other transformations to be retained, exept for the scale which needs to be `absolute`.

Comment: @Laurent What do you mean by *"scale needs to be `absolute`"*?

Comment: When pressing the button mutliple times, the scale should be set to 0.9 every time, instead of 0.9 of the current scale.

Comment: Then you should apply it only once. Because every time you apply `scale` to the scaled element it will change its size. Use [`jQuery.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to execute `click` event only once: http://jsfiddle.net/qET8N/2/.

Comment: The code I provided here is a stipped down, extremely simplified version of what I am actually trying to achieve. Therefore applying the scale only once will unfortunately not be an option.

Comment: @Laurent Didn't get your point. But if you don't want to use `one` make a backup of your transition property and apply the new `scale` value to the initial one on every click: http://jsfiddle.net/qET8N/3/.